# My jScrollPane doesn't work on my AbstractTableModel

Tags: java

I have created an `abstractTableModel` which auto fills through an array with data who takes from a select query.

This table is too long vertically talking so I need to apply a `JScrollPane`. But it is never showing up.

Here is the code:

```
String[][] Datos = crearArray(rs,numFilas);
TablaCryptos tC = new TablaCryptos( rs,columnas, Datos, numFilas);
JTable tabla = new JTable(tC);
FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
jPanel1.setLayout(fl);
JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(tabla);
        
jPanel1.add(tabla);
add(jPanel1);
add(js);
```

the table is inside `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

The JScrollPane contains the table because you passed it in with the constructor:

> `JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(tabla);`

So there is no need to add that table to another JPanel, which is then added to your layout as well:

> `jPanel1.add(tabla);`

I'd remove that line.  Your post doesn't really explain what kind of JFrame and main JPanel you've got, nor what layout, but I suspect that is a source of your layout problem.  Update your question if you need more help.

Comment: To be clear, when you are calling add add(js), you should review the layout of the panel you are adding the scroll pane to.

Comment: all related to jScrollPane is posted there, the class has JFrame extends implemented, I create a flowLayout and use it for the JPanel i dont have more lines of layout maybe the problem is with layout also had problems when my table didnt showed up because of layout... but dont know whats wrong with

Comment: fixed: solution after headaches: Adding js to the panel

String[][] Datos = crearArray(rs,numFilas);
TablaCryptos tC = new TablaCryptos( rs,columnas, Datos, numFilas);
            JTable tabla = new JTable(tC);
            JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(tabla);
            jPanel1.add(js);
            FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
            jPanel1.setLayout(fl);